# Can GeoNetwork store metadata for a PostGIS table?

Tags: postgis, geonetwork

Can GeoNetwork be used to store Metadata for a PostGIS table? Or is it only for WMS/WFS services?

If it can be used to create a store metadata for a PostGIS table, how is it done? I can't seem to find this in the GeoNetwork documentation.

Thanks.

DBlack

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this a lot too, and have come to the conclusion that it's not possible. The only way of doing it seems to be to create wms/wfs services from your postgis data, using geoserver or mapserver (for example) and then harvesting the metadata from these using geonetworks harvesting options. There are still some caveats to using this approach, which is that re-running the harvesting will over-write any changes made in geonetwork to the metadata. I'm not sure how to get around that yet!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah that is a bugger! I thought there would be a db option when filling out the distribution information, where you could specify the db and access constraints....oh well

Comment: I would like point your attention to this post to see if you guys can help me out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6540/geonetwork-not-searching-through-postgis-fields-via-geoserver-wms

Comment: Found us a solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finally this is being implemented. The 2.7 trunk version of GeoNetwork has this capability. It's called "OGC WFS GetFeature harvesting". You can specify the query on your PostGIS and map those fields to metadata using a template.

More info in the Harvesing Documentation:

https://geonetwork.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/geonetwork/trunk/docs/eng/users/source/admin/harvesting/index.rst

> .  ***OGC WFS GetFeature response***  Metadata can be present in the tables
>   of a relational databases, which are
>   commonly used by many organisations.
>   Putting an OGC Web Feature Service
>   (WFS) over a relational database will
>   allow metadata to be extracted via
>   standard query mechanisms. This
>   harvesting type allows the user to
>   specify a GetFeature query and map
>   information from the features to
>   fragments of metadata that can be
>   linked or copied into a template to
>   create metadata records.

Answer (score 0):

a straight answer to your question would be, sure. Just create a metadata for dataset (ISO19115) document in geonetwork for your (postgis) dataset using the geonetwork forms. But by reading the replies I noticed you probably wanted to ask: Can Geonetwork harvest the contents of a PostGis dataset (to be used as for example keywords in a metadata document)?

In that case the answer would be no. Geonetwork currently does not offer functionality to harvest metadata from postgis. But hey, what's the use-case here? Where in PostGis is the actual dataset-metadata to harvest (author, organisation, license). Usually one would add this metadata separate to the actual data in for example GeoNetwork...

But in case you just want to retrieve table-structure and contents to be used as keywords with your metadata. Have a look at OGC WFS GetFeature harvesting (GN-trunk/2.8RC1 to be released this weeks) or use a feature-catalog

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old but there finally seems to be some light at the end of the tunnel. I am still not 100% convinced but I have been trialling Talend with the Spatial Extension https://github.com/talend-spatial/workspace-metadata-crawler and it needs some work but does automated the process of connecting to a PostGIS database, crawl through the records and load them into GeoNetwork.The results I got are encouraging but still needs a lot of work to get further.